# In ffmpeg, why does rotate of 90 cause rotate of 270 to be listed?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I have a file ggg.mp4 with no rotational metadata.

```
C:\vidz>dir ggg.mp4
12/03/2020  17:50         9,304,867 ggg.mp4

C:\vidz>mediainfo ggg.mp4 | find "Rot"

C:\vidz>ffmpeg -i ggg.mp4 2>&1 | find "rotate"
```

I then try to create a file from that, with rotational metadata of 90 degrees

```
C:\vidz>ffmpeg -i ggg.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 ggg2.mp4

C:\vidz>ffmpeg -i ggg2.mp4 2>&1 | find "rotate"
      rotate          : 270

C:\vidz>mediainfo ggg2.mp4 | find "Rot"
Rotation                                 : 270

C:\vidz>
```

Why is there this discrepancy? 90 vs 270

**added**

```
C:\vidz>ffmpeg -i ggg2.mp4 2>&1 | find "rotat"
      rotate          : 270
      displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees

C:\vidz>
```

related- https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72473/is-there-a-media-player-that-can-be-told-to-aignore-rotational-metadata-bpay-a

Comment: i'm thinking it may have something to do with does one mean clockwise and the other anti clockwise, does one mean how much it needs (one way), and the other mean how much it has been rotated at the moment..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire readout will show something like this,

```
Metadata:
  rotate          : 270
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Side data:
  displaymatrix: rotation of 90.00 degrees
```

The first reading uses the old rotate API and is measured clockwise. The display matrix is signed and +ve is measured anti-clockwise, as is the CLI argument.

Comment: so ggg2 is rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise, or needs to be? and do you have documentation for which one means clockwise, which one means anti-clockwise, and whether it refers to what it needs or what it is.. Judging by VLC(which I think reads metadata), as opposed to WMP(which I think doesn't read metadata), it looks like metadata instructs for it to be rotated 90 degrees anticlockwise.

Comment: so in both cases it is instruction to the program playing it,  to rotate it by x degrees. In the fir reading old rotate api, it's clockwise, in the second case (displaymatrix:..) it's anti-clockwise

Comment: and mediainfo is describing like ffmpeg's first reading old rotate api, that the instruction is  for the video player to rotate it clockwise.